# update specific column in grid view

Tags: c#

I have a GridView which retrieves data from a database.  Users have roles, some of the users will update one column in the GridView and others will update a other columns according to roles see the code below!. I created the stored procedures as below and I added code.  When I tested the project,with role (AR-Translator)as example after edit column in grid view it replace other fieds with NULL value, so please what I can do?

**stored procedure**

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[GetAllTranslation]
 AS
BEGIN 
  Select Id,Word 
   ,Trans_AR
   ,Trans_EN
   ,Add_Date 
  From Translation 
END

ALTER Proc [dbo].[UpdateTranslation]
(
  @IdINT
  ,@Word NVARCHAR(MAX)
  ,@Trans_AR NVARCHAR(MAX)
  ,@Trans_EN NVARCHAR(MAX)


)
AS
BEGIN 
  UPDATE  Translation SET

  Word =@Word 
  ,Trans_AR=@Trans_AR 
  ,Trans_EN=@Trans_EN 

  WHERE Id=@Id
END
```

**aspx page**

```
 <div class="m10">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" 
    DataSourceID="SDSTrans" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Function" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Word" HeaderText="Word" SortExpression="Word" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Trans_AR" HeaderText="Trans_AR" 
            SortExpression="Trans_AR" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Trans_EN" HeaderText="Trans_EN" 
            SortExpression="Trans_EN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Add_Date" HeaderText="Add_Date" 
            SortExpression="Add_Date" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDSTrans" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=ELARABY-1EACFA3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ElarabyGroup;Integrated Security=True" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="GetAllTranslation" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="UpdateTranslation" 
        UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Id" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Word" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Trans_AR" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Trans_EN" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Label ID="ResultLBL" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

**CS**

```
public void CheckLoginAuthorty()
{
    using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("CheackLoginInRole", Con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewNVarChar("@Login", Session.Contents["Username"].ToString()));
        object O = com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (O != null)
        {
            string S = O.ToString();

            if (IsInRole("AR-Translator", O.ToString()))
            {

                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).ReadOnly = false;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).InsertVisible = false;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[4]).ReadOnly = false;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[4]).InsertVisible = false;


            }

            else if (IsInRole("EN-Translator", O.ToString()))
            {
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).ReadOnly = true;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).InsertVisible = false;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[3]).ReadOnly = true;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[3]).InsertVisible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the quesiton a bit more?  Can't quite understand what are your asking... do you want to manually update gridview columns?

Comment: it sounds like he is having issues with null characters... or maybe its nulling out a column?  I hope i translated correctly..

Comment: I edited the question I think you will understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to update your "update" SP like this

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[UpdateTranslation]
(
  @IdINT
  ,@Word NVARCHAR(MAX)
  ,@Trans_AR NVARCHAR(MAX)
  ,@Trans_EN NVARCHAR(MAX)


)
AS
BEGIN 
  UPDATE  Translation SET

  Word =isnull(@Word,Word)
  ,Trans_AR=isnull(@Trans_AR, Trans_AR)
  ,Trans_EN=isnull(@Trans_EN ,Trans_EN)

  WHERE Id=@Id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding, but if I do have the gist... default the nulls coming back from the database like so:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[GetAllTranslation]
 AS
BEGIN 
  Select Id
   ,isnull(Word,'') as 'Word'
   ,isnull(Trans_AR,'') as 'Trans_AR'
   ,isnull(Trans_EN,'') as 'Trans_EN'
   ,Add_Date
  From Translation 
END
```

Comment: the problem is still been .when i made update for specific column it replace other fields values with NULL value